# Survival analysis for matched set cohort data - Methods for absolute and relative risks?

Tags: survival, cox-model, poisson-regression

**BACKGROUND**

I have a matched data set with 10,000 cases and 20,000 controls. Cases are defined as such due to a diagnosis of COPD (Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease - a lung disease caused by smoking). Controls are healthy controls, matched for age and sex and region of residence. Cases and controls are not matched for socioeconomic variables, although I have that data as well. I have no other data for controls, although variables are plenty for cases. Mathching was done in the design phase of the study, and not during the analyses. to sum up, I have 10,000 cases with COPD and each individual has been matched to two age and sex matched controls.

**AIMS**
Estimate the excess risk of developing dementia among cases, as compared to controls.

**PLANNED METHODS**

• I Use R; the "survival" and "RMS" packages.

• I plan to use Cox proportional hazards regression for relative risks and some measure of incidence to estimate absolute risks. I have the following questions:

(1) should I take the matching property into account in the Cox regressions? If that is the case, how do You recommend me doing this? Should I use the cluster()-function? the strata()-function? Or could I just ignore the matching?

(2) When calculating the incidence rate (and incidence rate ratio) do I have to adjust anything; I'm asking because mean age and proportion of women is exactly the same in cases and controls (for obvious reasons). Should I go for Poisson based incidence rates? Any other methods to consider?

*I'd be very greateful for any advice on this.*

Comment: Did the matching process involve discarding any patient data that were already collected?  If so this is not a good application of matching and you should go back to the original larger cohort and do covariate adjustment without matching in my opinion.

Comment: Hi prof Harrell,
No it did not involve such a process. We haven't discarded any data actually. Matched controls are only used for one case. Controls have been selected from the general population, via registry-based procedures. I (although I'm not a statician) believe that the matching procedure has not introduced bias. I'm confused about whether and how to use the matching property in the final analyses.

Comment: I think you could use a stratified Cox model, in which a distinct underlying hazard function is allowed for each stratum (in this case each matched set). I'm not sure though.

Comment: You may be able to ignore the matching and do a regular covariable adjustment.  But see doi:10.1002/sim.5879, or http://www.citeulike.org/user/harrelfe/article/12464813 to see additional notes.